# Cython cdef no speed increase

Tags: python, c, cython

I finally got cython working thanks to some of the people here on stackoverflow, but now there is a problem. There really isn't a speed increase from when i don't use cdef to when i do use cdef. Don't get me wrong there was a very noticable speed increase when i compiled the python code using cython, but notsomuch when i use cdef.

This is the area of the code that was slowing down the rest of the program:

```
def tupdate(self,surf):     

    cdef int x
    cdef int y

    for x in xrange(self.w):
        for y in xrange(self.h):
            if self.map[(x,y)].y <= 600 and self.map[(x,y)].y >= -50: self.map[(x,y)].FLAG = 1
            else: self.map[(x,y)].FLAG = 0
            self.map[(x,y)].y += self.speed
            if self.map[(x,y)].FLAG:
                self.map[(x,y)].rect = ((self.map[(x,y)].x,self.map[(x,y)].y),(50,25))
                self.map[(x,y)].update()
                self.map[(x,y)].render(surf)
```

This code *should* be getting called 60 times a second, but due to the speed of the code and my older hardware its only getting called about 30 times a second, I figured using cdef for such intensely used vars like the x and y would help. But the fps is the same before and after cdef.

I'm on windows 7 64bit using 32bit python 2.7

Comment: I am only learning cython myself right now, but my first impression is that you might be using a bunch of calls that aren't optimized. Simply typing x and y would probably not be enough here.

Comment: `x` and `y` aren't the ones being intensely used...

Comment: Then which are the ones getting intenesly used? x and y are the indices for the loop?

Comment: self.map is a dictionary of all of the map data. How would i use cython to optimize that?

Comment: If I remember correctly, dictionaries can map to structs. So you would  have to type your `map` object accordingly so that cython could optimize the lookups. This is just a guess from what I know so far.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the obvious, but what are the dimensions you're looping through, w, and h? If these are at all large, this function will always take a long time. What is `tupdate` supposed to do?

Comment: @MattRoelle: Cython doesn't optimize `dict` lookups in any way. If you want better performance, you'll have to replace them by lower-level data structures, like C++ containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You index `self.map` **11 times** in the code, with the same index. Index it **once**, copying the reference into a local name, and then use that name.

Comment: I might be wrong, but its also worth mentioning that typing x and y aren't particularly useful in this context because nothing much is being done with them other than using them as indexes... am I right?

Comment: What's worse is that they need to be *detyped* when put in the tuple for the index operation.

Comment: Thanks! Just that alone gave me a good speed increase. However, self.map is a dictionary of a Block object. Is there any way to cdef an object?

Comment: @MattRoelle: look at [cdef classes](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html).